# Exception when EditText is placed after Buttons

Tags: android, layout

The following layout gives an error upon the application starts

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/hud"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#2D4673"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="b1" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/b2"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="b2" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/b3"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="b3" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/b4"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="b4" >
    </Button>

    <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="#2D4673"
        android:textColor="#BCD6E0"
        android:textSize="36dp"
        android:typeface="monospace" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

However when the TextView is placed before the Buttons in the same LinearLayout, it works properly.

What is the problem here?

Comment: What is the error output?

Comment: Why are you declaring the namespace on every tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the namespace `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` for all your tags except for the parent layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/hud"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#2D4673"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="b1" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b2"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="b2" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b3"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="b3" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b4"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="b4" >
    </Button>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="#2D4673"
        android:textColor="#BCD6E0"
        android:textSize="36dp"
        android:typeface="monospace" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```